# Node.js Addon Require multiple times new instace

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-addon

How can I avoid cache with require('c++addon'). I have an addon but will like to have a new one every time.

e.g

```
for(...)
 addon[i] = require('addon'); // I want a new one everytime
 addon[i].somefunction(); //
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to refactor your addon module so it exposes a function to construct these instances, e.g.

```
const myAddon = require('addon');
objects = [myAddon.create(), myAddon.create(), myAddon.create()];
objects[0].somefunction();
```

Comment: I thought there was another way

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code doing multiple instances of native object creations. 
https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/blob/master/6_object_wrap/napi/myobject.cc

If you are dealing with The native module, then the native module will have to write some extra code to create a new instance too. In addition to creating a new instance the native module also needs to take care of lifetime management of the instance as well. There are two ways a typical JavaScript code initiate create an object. One is by using its constructor and the other one is by using a function call. The native module responsible for creating the new instance also has to deal with differently for this two. You may get more insight by referring documentation about the following along with the example code https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html

- Lifetime management:
  napi_ref
  napi_create_reference()
- To check whether it is a constructor call or not
  napi_get_new_target()
- To instantiate a new JavaScript object based on an existing native
  object (of type napi_value)
  napi_new_instance()